# mongodb index data structures

Tags: database-design, mongodb

Does mongodb discriminate between indices constructed of small, statically sized elements (lets say numeric types) and those with large variant types (such as strings) ?

From the BSON spec I can see that BSON does show the capacity of special treatment of integral types. I would expect the indexing code to create more performant indices if the index contains only int64's.

Perhaps it has some form of discriminated union ?

Comment: What do you mean by discriminate? You can tell MongoDB to use specific indexes in your queries so it utilizes the best index for your query; you can test your indexes to see which one is faster for a specific query. I would assume an index on a numeric value would be more performant than an alphanumeric index due to the nature of the data.

Comment: Before a database engine can decide on the structure it will use for a index data type, it needs to know what is going to be put into that data type. Since mongodb does not restrict you either some heuristic is in use or a discriminated union is used as a data structure for indexed values. If a heuristic is in use I'd like to know what to expect.

Answer (score 4):

The B-Tree contents are basically just the BSON serialized representation of the indexed fields and a pointer to the disk location of that object.

Here is a [link to the code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/btree.cpp#L754) where it mentions this. In fact, here is the [`woCompare` function](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/jsobj.cpp#L445-519) they use while looping through the index.

Looks to me like a simple binary comparison, so smaller data will compare faster than larger data.

Comment: Links are both dead now