# Creating a User ID that is indexable by database

Tags: mongodb, database-indexes, database

I'm creating a REST service that allows user profiles to be created.  The issue is that I want to create a user ID for each user.  I can use a random hex number to describe each unique user, but I'm not sure if this is efficient for database indexed search.

How would one create a user ID so that it can be quickly looked up when it needs to and can be indexed easily for fast look up?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the field user_id indexes which may result in fast lookup:

1. Use mongodb's _id field which is indexed default. You can store
   user_is in this field. This gives two advantages:

   - a. You can use existing field instead of creating new filed to store
     user id
   - b. You can save on creating extra index.
2. Secondly, you can create new filed user_id that stores user if for each user and can be indexed using:

   db.ensureIndex({user_id:1}, {background:true})

Comment: For the 2nd method, must I use numbers that increment to ensure a good index or can I use Hex values or strings that contains A-Z0-9??

Comment: Mongodb allows different type of fields to index.  You can create index both integer type and hex

Comment: What is general best practice?  If my resource url contains the mongodb _id it would seem very long.  Is it better then to use just a numbered Id which is shorter?

Comment: Please look at adam's answer on this post. looks more helpful                                                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024362/does-field-type-matter-in-a-mongodb-index