# String vs. Number Comparison Efficiency in MongoDB

Tags: string, mongodb, mongoose, numbers

Suppose that I querying by an arbitrary field `category` that will be four characters long with all numbers.

So, it could be `'1234'`, `'2341'`, `'9999'` etc.

Now, if I am certain that this numerical representation of this string will be greater than or equal to 1000 and less than or equal to 9999, does making this field a `number` instead of a `string` make the query more efficient? I believe that number comparisons are more efficient than string comparisons, but I am not sure that it will have any discernible effect on the query performance. I believe that making this field a `string` would be better if query performance is equal because the field categories number is just an identifier and therefore a string is more descriptive of what is going on, but better query performance is more important.

Therefore, my question is if I query on this arbitrary `category` field will it be more efficient to query by string or by number or that it doesn't matter?

Comment: Numbers are always better than string for searching. Indexing also play major role in search performance.

Comment: Ask yourself this basic question. *"How many bytes in the string '1234'?"*, And then ask *"How many bytes would be used by the number `1234`?"*. If you can't remember this from class or something you read then look it up, but one hint is the default BSON type for that number unless otherwise specified is `Double` ( which should be a big hint in the name ). After your conclusion on those then what seems logical from *"Does the bigger or smaller thing process faster?"*. Then you will have your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12024423/5919473) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995422/5919473) index is represented as BSON document in binary form.

Efficiency can be gained by making it small (index just what is needed) rather than playing with data types.